# save different elements in array by a condition

Tags: javascript

How can I save elements in an array based on a condition? In the following array, if I pass an age, it returns the array with the elements that meet that condition, but if I pass an age that does not exist or nothing happens when calling the function, how can I add all the elements of array1 to array2

```
const array1 = [
  {
    name: 'jose',
    country: 'argentina',
    age: 20
  },
  {
    name: 'pedro',
    country: 'brazil',
    age: 18
  },
  {
    name: 'andrea',
    country: 'mexico',
    age: 20
  },
  {
    name: 'luis',
    country: 'eu',
    age: 19
  },
  {
    name: 'nancy',
    country: 'mexico',
    age: 18
  }
];
const getDatos = (age) => {
  const array2 = array2.filter(data=> data.age === age);
  console.log(array2 )
}
getDatos(20);
```

Comment: If I understand you right, you want it so if nothing was found after filtering, it falls back to putting everything from array1 into array2? How about `const tempArray = array.filter(...); const array2 = tempArray.length > 0 ? tempArray : array1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if this is what you want, but you can check if the age is in the array using `Array.prototype.some`([MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some))

```js
const getDatos = (age) => {
  if (array1.some(data => data.age === age)) {
    return array1.filter(data=> data.age === age);
  } else {
    return array1;
  }
}
```

EDIT: Based on Sebastian Simons comment, this approach it's better

```js
const getDatos = (age) => {
  const results = array1.filter(data => data.age === age);

  return results.length > 0 ? results : array1;
}
```

Comment: This iterates over the array twice, unnecessarily. Just check the length of the result of `filter`.

Comment: It doesn't always iterate twice using some, at the first element that age is equal to the age parameter, it stops and returns true, but yeah, checking the length feels more appropiated now

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) `?` to check the [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) of array returned by `filter`. If any matches are found, return them, otherwise return all records.

```
const all = [
  { name: 'jose', country: 'argentina', age: 20 },
  { name: 'pedro', country: 'brazil', age: 18 },
  { name: 'andrea', country: 'mexico', age: 20 },
  { name: 'luis', country: 'eu', age: 19 },
  { name: 'nancy', country: 'mexico', age: 18 }
];

const getDatos = (age) => {
  let matches = all.filter(data => data.age === age);
  return (matches.length) ? matches : all;
}

console.log(getDatos(20)); // jose & andrea
console.log(getDatos(99)); // all records
```